# Breaking single polygon into multiple polygons?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I created voronoi polygons after which I dissolved them on the basis of one attribute. Now there are cases where in for one single attribute "abc" I have3 polygons at different places with same object id. I would like to break these into 3 polygons as they are at different locations.

Is there any tool in ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS which can help me in doing that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that what you actually want to do is to convert multipart polygons into singlepart polygons.

In ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) it can be done using [Multipart To Singlepart (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/) tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by separating multipart input features.

Answer (score 22):

In QGIS vector menu, as well as in the Processing Toolbox, you'll find **Multipart To Singlepart**.

> This algorithm takes a vector layer with multipart geometries and generates a new one in which all geometries contain a single part. Features with multipart geometries are divided in as many different features as parts the geometry contain, and the same attributes are used for each of them.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You should specify option `SINGLE_PART` when running ArcGIS [Dissolve tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000):

> SINGLE_PART —Specifies multipart features are not allowed. Instead of
>   creating multipart features, individual features will be created for
>   each part.

Answer (score 3):

Another Less elegant option is to click the **Explode** button in **Advanced Editing toolbar** in Arcgis after selecting all features in Layer.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for all you R enthusiasts or new learners (like myself) out there: The same thing can be achieved in R with the `disaggregate` function from the `sp` library.

```
output <- disaggregate(input)
```

Simple as that.