# How to transform a selected multipart feature into singlepart features while editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

There are several questions and respective answers for how to make a multipart features Layer into a  singlepart features one using QGIS:

- [How to break a single polygon into multiple polys?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27825/how-to-break-a-single-polygon-into-multiple-polys)
- [How to split non-contiguous feature in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23377/how-to-split-non-contiguous-feature-in-qgis)

But all the solutions I saw, create entirely new layer and would transform ALL the multipart geometries into single ones.

So the questions is, how could one, during an edit session, **selectively** transform a multipart feature into a singlepart feature, without the need to create new layers?

It would be the opposite to the "merge selected features" tool, and similar to [explode](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Merging_and_separating_features) in ArcGIS.

Is there any plugin doing this? How could this be done using the python console?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inspired by this [question & answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/switch-line-direction-in-qgis) as an example of how "easily" can one make its own solutions when using Open Source, I have tried to create my own code to selectively "explode" multipart features during an editing session.

I have explored the [QGIS 1.8 API](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/) for the first time, and came out with this piece of code that seams to do the job:

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
remove_list = []

for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    # check if feature geometry is multipart
    if geom.isMultipart():
        remove_list.append(feature.id())
        new_features = []
        temp_feature = QgsFeature(feature)
        # create a new feature using the geometry of each part
        for part in geom.asGeometryCollection ():
            temp_feature.setGeometry(part)
            new_features.append(QgsFeature(temp_feature))
        # add new features to layer
        layer.addFeatures(new_features, False)

# remove the original (multipart) features from layer
if len(remove_list) > 0:
    for id in remove_list:
        layer.deleteFeature (id)
```

I'm not an experienced programmer, so the code might not be the most efficient one.

Next steep will be to make a plugin out of it... Or at least, try to!

**UPDATE:**
I was able to create the plugin. It's called [Multipart Split](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/), and can be found in the QGIS official repository.

Comment: Would it be possible to work this Multipart -> Singlepart conversion without QGIS? Is there a way it can be done with Standalone Python? 
@Alexandre Neto

Comment: Notice that this solution rely on selecting part of a layer's features during edit in map canvas. To convert all features of a layer (say shapefile) into single part features I think you can use OGR library. Have a look in this [link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Multipart-to-singlepart-tt3746767.html#a3746770).

Comment: Cheers! Helps..!!

Comment: I want to take a layer that is one multipart polygon and convert it single part - I can't seem to find the python code to do this in qgis. I see there is a command under vector--geometry tools--Multiparts to Singleparts. this is what I want I just need the python syntax

Comment: @AlexandreNeto great plugin!