# How to export qgis as a kml file?

Tags: kml, convert, google

I have a .qgis contour plot. 
 I would like to convert this to a .kml file.
 How specifically would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Layer>Save As (Select KML)

[Data is in OSGB36 Ordnance Survey GB]

[image]

[image]

Open in Google Earth to check it is in the correct position

Comment: When I do this, it says "invalid variant type for field Precip_min[3]"

Comment: is your number in a string field?

Comment: I don't think so. It goes like "34.23 -75.23 45" across one row. here is a link to the error http://www.geocities.ws/radar/error.png

Comment: looks like you have multi-part polygons - you might need to make single part polygons first.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64836/how-can-i-turn-islands-into-individual-features-in-qgis >geometry tools