# Bounding box styling of individual parts of multipart objects

Tags: qgis, style, vector-layer, multipart, singlepart

In my QGIS project I have a multi-linestring vector layer where each multi-linestring feature consists of small not connected linestrings.

I would like to show a bounding box around each of the parts of each multi-linestring object like in the following example:

[image: One multilinestring object with styling of each single part object]

If I use the following styling

```
bounds($geometry)
```

I just get a bounding box around the entire multi-linestring object.

Is it possible to visualise the bounding box of each of the parts of the multi-linestring objects without creating a new single part dataset?

Comment: maybe a custom function based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44799/how-to-transform-a-selected-multipart-feature-into-singlepart-features-while-edi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small test sample as below:

(1) A `multipart` line layer.

[image]

(2) Created a polygon by geometry generator `bounds($geometry)`. One large box encompasses all lines, as you have pointed out...

[image]

(3) So I used `bounds(geometry_n($geometry, @geometry_part_num))`, to create a box for each line.

[image]

Hope these red boxes (dashed) are what you were looking for.

Comment: @Chau Probably out of your scope...... I had spent hours trying to change the color for each box without success......  =(

Comment: thanks for looking into this! I had long forgot about this but will use get back to it again now :)