# Split disconnected polygons into separate features after using clip tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, clip, intersect

I'm working with a series of forest polygons (geodatabase feature classes), which I'm trying to clip to an area with a specific land use history (marked as "undisturbed" in the screenshot below)in ArcGIS 10.3.1. I'm then hoping to filter out all polygons less than 1 hectare for additional analysis.

My problem is that some of of the forest polygons ("cove_ecogroup" below) overlap the larger land use polygon in multiple areas, which leaves me with some disconnected features in my output. This is fine, except that it makes my 1-hectare filter impossible because these shapes are being stored as larger than they actually are because they retain the FID of the original feature instead of splitting into multiple new features (See image 2).

Is there a way to split these into multiple features so that I can filter out everything under 1 hectare? This analysis covers hundreds of thousands of acres, and so I won't be able to edit each new polygon individually.

[image: Image 1: View of the overlapping features]

[image: Image 2: Single attribute for disconnected shape]

Comment: This [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27825/36484) may help you

Comment: Use multipart to singlepart tool

Comment: As Felix mentioned. And in an edit session you can use the explode command from the advanced editing toolbar